# Routing Error - No route matches when using button_to with custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following button to download a file.

```
= button_to 'download', action: 'download', method: 'get'
```

And I have a `download` method under MoviesController like this

```
# movies_controller.rb
def download
  …
end
```

However, I get the following error. Any idea how to solve this?

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"download", :method=>"get", :controller=>"movies"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :movies do
  get 'download', on: :member
end
```

Now, in your view you need to specify, what movie you want to download:

```
= button_to 'download', download_movie_path(@movie), method: 'get'
```

Also, note:

1. Use `path` instead of specifying `controller/action` in helpers.
2. Use `link_to` for `GET` requests and if you need link with button style apply it through CSS. `button_to` with `GET` request is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work with your view code just change into **routes.rb**

```
resources :movies do
    get :download, :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: I think it should be `:on => :member` instead since it's not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to specify controller/action (which has advantages, since it allows you to pass through arbitrary params), you'll need to also explicitly pass along any parameters that action relies on (assuming you're trying to download an individual movie, and not the entire collection).

```
button_to 'download', {controller: 'movies', action: 'download', id: movie.id }, method: 'get'
```

Also, ditto Mikhail D's point about using link_to for "get" requests. Defining the method explicitly is great for sending requests to the "update" action (by setting method: :patch or method: :puts), but for "gets" just use link_to.