# Routing error - No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Have read many questions / answers on this issue, yet do not seem to find my fix.

Here is the issue: I am following the getting started for Rails to create a simple register of annotations. My forms work - can add new & update annotations. Yet when I add links to the index, I get a routing error:

- This: `<%= button_to "Details", annotation_path(annotation), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-xs"%>` results in: No route matches [POST] "/annotations/5"
- This: `<%= button_to "Add Annotation", new_annotation_path, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-xs"%>` to **No route matches [POST] "/annotations/new"**

Thanks for help

**Routes.db:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'dashboard#index'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users, :annotations
```

**Controller:**

```
class AnnotationsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @annotations = Annotation.all
    end

    def show
        @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @annotation = Annotation.new
    end

    def edit
        @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @annotation = Annotation.new(annotation_params)

        @annotation.save
        redirect_to @annotation
    end

    def update
        @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])

        if @annotation.update(annotation_params)
            redirect_to @annotation
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @annotation = Annotation.find(params[:id])
        @annotation.destroy

        redirect_to annotations_path
    end

    private
        def annotation_params
            params.require(:annotation).permit(:name, :description)
        end
end
```

And the **form** (= partial)

```
<%= simple_form_for @annotation, url: annotations_path, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' },
    wrapper: :horizontal_form,
    wrapper_mappings: {
        check_boxes: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        radio_buttons: :horizontal_radio_and_checkboxes,
        file: :horizontal_file_input,
        boolean: :horizontal_boolean
    } do |f| %>

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Enter name' %>

    <%= f.input :description, placeholder: 'Description' %>

    <%= f.input :file, as: :file %>

    <%= f.input :active, as: :boolean %>

    <%= f.input :choice, as: :check_boxes,
    collection: [
      'Option one ...',
      'Option two ...'] %>

    <%= f.input :documenttype, as: :radio_buttons,
    collection: ['Type1', 'Type2'] %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Note on the form: to no avail, I tried using `<%= simple_form_for :annotation, url: annotations_path,`

Comment: add `method: :get`. `button_to` does `POST` request by default while your those routes are `GET`

Comment: Also, I insist on investigating the error logs carefully. The question itself says 'POST' route is not matched, that means that route doesn't exist and you can check why that's the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing Error - No route matches when using button\_to with custom action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650213/routing-error-no-route-matches-when-using-button-to-with-custom-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the button_to helper actually generates a form at code level and thus is POSTing said form, however the route for a new resource must be a GET.

The button_to tag really should not be used for GET requests so I would use a link_to with CSS classes instead (you already have the necessary classes), but you can do it using the below if you wanted:

```
<%= button_to "Details", annotation_path(annotation), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs", method: :get%>
```

The better approach however is:

```
<%= link_to "Details", annotation_path(annotation), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>
```

Comment: good advice for the better approach. In what cases should I then use button_to? Only for POSTing?

Comment: I would say you should also use it for a PUT\PATCH (update) action but that would require specifying the method on the helper as above i/e :patch or :put.

Answer (score 0):

Read doc here [button_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to)

The method is by default `:post` change it using `:method` param

```
<%= button_to "Details", annotation_path(annotation), :class => "btn btn-primary btn-xs", method: :get%>

<%= button_to "Add Annotation", new_annotation_path, :class => "btn btn-primary btn-xs", method: :get%>
```